# Maven Checkstyle Plugin - Change location of file checkstyle-checker.xml in ${project.build.directory}

Tags: java, maven, maven-checkstyle-plugin

Trying to clean up my `${project.build.directory}`, I noticed that `maven-checkstyle-plugin` puts three files into my `target` folder: `checkstyle-checker.xml`, `checkstyle-cachefile` and `checkstyle-result.xml`.

I was able to redirect the last two into their own folder `target/checkstyle`:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <cacheFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-cachefile"/>
      <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
     [...]
      <outputFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml">${checkstyle.output.file}</outputFile>
    </configuration>
    [...]
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

All I could find about `checkstyle-checker` is under [propertiesLocation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#propertiesLocation).
There is says:

> If successfully resolved, the contents of the properties location is copied into the ${project.build.directory}/checkstyle-checker.properties file before being passed to Checkstyle for loading.

Can I change the location the contents of the properties location are copied into? Or is there another way to make the plugin write the `checkstyle-checker.xml` file into my custom folder `target/checkstyle`?

Comment: nice task, but "best practice" to "clean up my 'target folder'" is (still): `mvn clean` (and sleep tight;)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the location of `${project.build.directory}/checkstyle-checker.properties` without modifying/overwriting the plugin.

The documentation sounds clear regarding this point.

A gaze into the [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/checkstyle/exec/DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java#L421) reveals, that `checkstyle-checker.properties` is hard coded. ... and the path (`${project.build.directory}`) is "deep in" maven/plexus.

Same applies to (the location of) `checkstyle-checker.xml`: [DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java#L723](https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/checkstyle/exec/DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java#L723)